# Visual Studio Code & gulp

Tags: visual-studio-code, gulp

I had a question about Visual Studio Code & gulp.

I'm using typescript version 3.7.2 with the latest version of Visual Studio Code.
When I run gulp build, I get the following output:

```
[12:03:36] Starting gulp
[12:03:36] Starting 'build'...
[12:03:36] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
[12:03:36] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 6.42 ms
[12:03:36] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[12:03:36] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 55 ms
[12:03:36] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[12:03:36] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[12:03:37] Finished subtask 'sass' after 1.38 s
[12:03:37] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[12:03:39] [tslint] tslint version: 5.12.1
[12:03:39] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[12:03:39] [tsc] typescript version: 2.9.2
[12:03:40] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 4.46 s
[12:03:48] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 10 s
[12:03:49] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 10 s
[12:03:49] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[12:03:49] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 428 μs
[12:03:49] Finished 'build' after 14 s
[12:03:50] ==================[ Finished ]==================
```

My question is about 1 line specifically:

```
[12:03:39] [tsc] typescript version: 2.9.2
```

Why is it using typescript version 2.9.2 when I have 3.7.2 installed?
Is there a way to change this?

**Edit:**

full gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');

build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

// Taken from: https://blog.mastykarz.nl/correctly-reference-images-sharepoint-framework-solutions/
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
  additionalConfiguration: generatedConfiguration => {
    if (build.getConfig().production) {

      var basePath = build.writeManifests.taskConfig.cdnBasePath;
      if (!basePath.endsWith('/')) {
        basePath += '/';
      }

      generatedConfiguration.output.publicPath = basePath;
    }
    else
    {
      generatedConfiguration.output.publicPath = '/dist/';
    }

    return generatedConfiguration;
  },
});

build.initialize(gulp);
```

I'm using gulp **3.9.1**. 
I tried upgrading but ran into issues so I had to downgrade.

Comment: Can you add the build function in `gulpfile.js` in your question ? Also, what version of gulp are you using ?

Comment: stud3nt, I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an article that led me in the right direction [HERE](https://www.eliostruyf.com/define-the-typescript-version-you-want-to-use-in-sharepoint-framework/).
Now I see the following:

```
[tsc] typescript version: 3.3.4000
```

Still not using 3.7.2 but, I guess it's good enough.
Hope this helps someone else...

Comment: I have the same problem with my tslint and typescript. While I have 5.20.1 and 3.7.4 installed, It still is doing what yours did. I wish I knew where it was pulling that tslint 5.12.1 and tsc 2.9.2.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694844/gulp-serve-throws-error-error-tslint-no-valid-rules-have-been-specified-fo